# No funciona el atributo required en el elemento select

Tags: html5, select2, html-select

Tengo un formulario en mi proyecto laravel, en el cual quiero validar ciertos campos, el caso es que utilizo el atributo **required** de `HTML5`, la cosa es que solo me funciona en los elementos **input** en cambio en los **select** no funciona ni uno.. da igual si es un `select` normal o un `select2`.

Alguien sabría decirme si hay alguna incompatibilidad con **Laravel** o algo?

```
<select id="hola" name="hola" required>.
     <option value="" selected>
          Choose option
     </option>
     <option value="hello_world">
          Hello world!
     </option>
     <option value="goodbye_world">
          Goodbye world!
     </option>
</select>
```

En otros proyectos esto funciona perfectamente, pero no sé si con laravel hay otra manera, sin usar `validator`, ni `JS Validate`, ni nada, simplemente quiero usar el required de `HTML5`.

Aunque quite el **selected** sigue del **option** sigue haciendo lo mismo, en teoría al tener **value=""** al hacer submit debería saltar igual.

Answer (score 3):

El problema que tienes es que siempre tiene un valor el select, me explico:

Si pones esto:

```
<select id="hola" name="hola" required>
     <option value="hello_world" selected>
          Hello world!
     </option>
     <option value="goodbye_world">
          Goodbye world!
     </option>
</select>
```

Tu has puesto que la primera opcion siempre este select y ademas, le añades un valor, si quieres que la primera opcion no cuente como required, le tienes que quitar el valor, y ademas como está puesta la primera no tienes que poner selected, porque ya va a salir por defecto. Ejemplo:

```
<select id="hola" name="hola" required>
     <option value="">
          Hello world!
     </option>
     <option value="goodbye_world">
          Goodbye world!
     </option>
</select>
```

Espero que te funcione

Answer (score 3):

Para agregar a la respuesta de Alberto, la documentación dice:

> Un elemento **select** con un atributo **required** y sin un atributo multiple, y cuyo size es "1", debe tener un elemento **option** hijo.
>
> El primer elemento hijo **option** de un elemento **select** con un atributo **required** y sin un atributo multiple y cuyo size es "1", debe tener un atributo **value** vacío o no debe tener contenido de texto.

https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/select.html

---

Esto se traduce en estas posibilidades de escribir un campo vacío:

```
<select required aria-required="true" id="hola" name="hola">
  <option value="">Choose</option>
  ...
</select>
```

Si quieres tener la opción vacía:

```
<select required aria-required="true" id="hola" name="hola">
  <option>&nbsp;</option>
  ...
</select>
```

También puedes usar un espacio en vez de `&nbsp;`